# what is statistics uncertainty on a quizz score?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

Remark : I have created the question from scratch : it is not my teachers who asked me that. I'm wondering myself about a general problem of uncertainty.

Let's consider a 'school' quizz with D numbers of questions (D as 'denominator) of the type yes/no for which the student earns 1 point or 0 point if he is correct or not.

Let's consider that the student successes in N questions (N as 'numerator'): 
His score efficiency is eff=N/D
(it represents a fraction of correct answer, with score within [0 ; 1], 1 meaning 100 % of correct answers)

How to compute the *statistical uncertainty* on the score efficiency of a student.

Is it sqrt(eff(1-eff)/N) as in the uncertainties of 'efficiencies' ?

Is it sqrt(N / D) ?

Is it something else ?
(and why) ?

Thank you for your kind help or tips

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "statistical uncertainty"?

Comment: The score on the test is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(D, p),$ where $p$ is the (often unknown) probability of answering any one question correctly. $E(X) = Dp$ and $Var(X) = Dp(1-p),$ An estimate of $p$ is $\hat p= X/D.$ So an estimate of $Var(X)$ is $D\hat p(1-\hat p).$

Comment: @Bruce The main message in your comment is that the meaning of "uncertainty" *depends on adopting some kind of probability model for the score.*  The binomial model is neither the only possibility nor even the most plausible in this scenario.  (What would justify assuming the results are independent and have equal probabilities?)

Comment: @whuber. Point taken. I suppose there is no absolutely correct model and variance is clearly not the only measure of 'uncertainty.' Make that, "Suppose the score on the test ...."

Comment: Hi. By statistical uncertainty : I mean the "error bar" on the score. Indeed, the goal of a quizz is to have an idea on the level of the student. If there would be an infinite number of questions, the score would be the "exact" level of the score. Due to the limited number of questions, the score is biased with respect to the exact unknown level of the student. That is, for an infinite number of questions, the statistical uncertainty should be exactly 0. I see that your sqrt(Var) would not give 0 if D=infinity. Does my comment make you change your mind ?

Comment: In addition to my previous comment : I would have thought that the statistical uncertainty (=uncertainty error on the score) would not depend on a modelization : do you confirm that there is no "definite" uncertainty on the score and that we should for sure make a "model" ?

Comment: remark : actually, I believe that the error should not be sqrt{Var(X)}, but sqrt{Var(X/D)}, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Further comments:

As mentioned in @whuber's Comments, a coherent discussion of statistical uncertainty requires a probability model. From some of the suggestions in your Question and comments, it seems you may be thinking of a binomial probability model.
Binomial models are often---perhaps *too often*---used to model test scores. So that may be an idea worth exploring as you continue to think about your problem.

Also, you mention 'error bars' as one approach to dealing with uncertainty, which brings confidence intervals to mind. 
And some of your suggestions seem similar to approaches that have been
used to make confidence intervals for binomial proportions (perhaps
what you mean by 'efficiency scores').

[This link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372894/calculating-sampling-proportions-standard-deviation-given-population-proportion/372928#372928) and similar ones (see 'Related' links on that page) discuss various kinds
of binomial confidence intervals.  It might be worth your while to
look there and in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).

If that is what you're looking for, fine. If not, maybe looking at such
pages will help you to formulate your question more clearly, so you might get answers in more
helpful directions.

Comment: Your Wikipedia hyperlink doesn't go where I think you intended it to go.

Comment: @Noah.  Thanks. Right about that. Fixing it.